# Passing parameter through permalink structure

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls

I have a WordPress post which is accessible via domain.com/test/

What I want to be able to do is pass in a parameter using the URL - ie going to domain.com/test/ would load the same page as domain.com/test/ - but in url show the /accommodation/value1/**?m=1** in the browser address bar.

I guess another way of putting it would be to say I need to be able to access domain.com/test/ by adding **?m=1** like to the end of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you will add the parameter to the URL on a different page. For example:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/test?m=1">Details about M1</a>
```

This is because the parameter affects what the server loads. So you can't go to the URL and then add the parameter after load. That's not what its for.

Comment: I have tried that but wordpress is giving 404 error

Comment: Very likely it is unrelated to the url parameter itself. Possibly, the presence of the parameter triggers some php code that has an error. You will use $_GET['m'] to grab the value.

Comment: Hi rob thanks for reply, i have do some study on this topic and found that **m=** parameter is use for month. Can you help me to add **&m=1** parameter in end of url

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply

i have tweak my code and its working for me

```
add_action("init","remove_m_parameter");
function remove_m_parameter()
{
    if(isset($_GET['m']))
    {
    unset($_GET['m']);
    }
}
```